# How to set Class member variables in php

Tags: php, class, variables, member

I'm getting following error shown below while setting class member variables. How to set member variables in php like we normally do in `c#.net`

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `T_VAR`, expecting `T_VARIABLE` ,Kindly help me out to fix it. I'm newbie in PHP

```
<?php

class clsCustomer{

       public var $customercode;
       public var $customername;
       public var $customeraddress;


       public function PrintCustomerDetails(){

        echo $this->customercode." ".$this->customername." ".$this->customeraddress;      
       }

}

$obj = new clsCustomer();

$obj->customercode = 1;
$obj->customername = "Shiv";
$obj->customeraddress = "Mumbai India";

$obj->PrintCustomerDetails();

?>
```

Comment: Nowadays people start coding without reading a single line of the syntax for the current language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `var` keywords from the property declarations:

```
class clsCustomer{

   public $customercode;
   public $customername;
   public $customeraddress;

   ...

}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
- [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)